# how to set a background color in UIimage in swift programming

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

I draw an image using `drawInRect()` method.

My rectangle is size of 120*120 and my image is 100 * 100.

How i can set a background color to my image in swift?

Comment: `UIImage` of course does not have a `.backgroundColor`.  The commentor is thinking of `UIImageView`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can also use this extension:

```swift
    extension UIImage {
        func imageWithColor(tintColor: UIColor) -> UIImage {
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.size, false, self.scale)

            let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
            context.translateBy(x: 0, y: self.size.height)
            context.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0);
            context.setBlendMode(.normal)

            let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.size.width, height: self.size.height) as CGRect
            context.clip(to: rect, mask: self.cgImage!)
            tintColor.setFill()
            context.fill(rect)

            let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

            return newImage
        }
    }
```

And then

```
image.imageWithColor("#1A6BAE".UIColor)
```

EDIT: 2019-11: Updated to Swift 5 by @Yuto

Answer (score 27):

### Swift 5, 4

If you need to draw the background of an image, for optimization and decorative purposes, you can draw the image in a specific way:

`UIImage(named: "someImage")?.withBackground(color: .white)`

---

#### Extension

```
extension UIImage {
  func withBackground(color: UIColor, opaque: Bool = true) -> UIImage {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, opaque, scale)
        
    guard let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), let image = cgImage else { return self }
    defer { UIGraphicsEndImageContext() }
        
    let rect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size)
    ctx.setFillColor(color.cgColor)
    ctx.fill(rect)
    ctx.concatenate(CGAffineTransform(a: 1, b: 0, c: 0, d: -1, tx: 0, ty: size.height))
    ctx.draw(image, in: rect)
        
    return UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() ?? self
  }
}
```

Comment: This should be accepted. The accepted one change the image color not its background. 
But this code do the work. Thanks

Comment: its not the/a`'backgroundColor` property but wonderful code!

Answer (score 9):

Updated @Egghead's solution for Swift 3

```
extension UIImage {
   static func imageWithColor(tintColor: UIColor) -> UIImage {
        let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 1)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, false, 0)
        tintColor.setFill()
        UIRectFill(rect)
        let image: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image
    }
}
```

Usage :

```
UIImage.imageWithColor(tintColor: <Custom color>)
```

Answer (score 4):

It's probably best to use the backgroundColor property of your UIImageView. You can do this as follows -

```
self.imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
```

The following preset colors exist:

```
blackColor
darkGrayColor
lightGrayColor
whiteColor
grayColor
redColor
greenColor
blueColor
cyanColor
yellowColor
magentaColor
orangeColor
purpleColor
brownColor
clearColor
```

If you instead want to programmatically create a UIImage with a given color, you can do this as follows:

```
var rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0)
color.setFill()
UIRectFill(rect)
var image: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

Where the `var` 'image' is your colored UIImage.

Comment: this backgroundColor property work fine but when  i save the image the the background color is still white

Comment: so i use this code  UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(120,120), false, 1.0)
        let rect2 = CGRectMake(0, 0, displayImage.size.width, displayImage.size.height)
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        UIColor.redColor().set()
        CGContextFillRect( context, rect2)
        displayImage.drawInRect(rect2)
        image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();                                                                      //displayImage is size of 100 * 100

Answer (score 4):

An other way to obtain an image with a background color with an extension is:  (Swift 3)

```
extension UIImage {

    /**
        Returns an UIImage with a specified background color.
        - parameter color: The color of the background
     */
    convenience init(withBackground color: UIColor) {

        let rect: CGRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 1)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
        let context:CGContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!;
        context.setFillColor(color.cgColor);
        context.fill(rect)

        let image:UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        self.init(ciImage: CIImage(image: image)!)

    }
}
```

And then:

```
// change UIColor.white with your color
let image = UIImage(withBackground: UIColor.white)
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution for swift 4 based on the already acepted answer:

```
func imageWithColor(tintColor: UIColor) -> UIImage {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.size, false, self.scale)

    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() as! CGContext
    context.translateBy(x: 0, y: size.height)
    context.scaleBy(x: 1, y: -1)
    context.setBlendMode(.normal)

    let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.size.width, height: self.size.height) as CGRect
    context.clip(to: rect, mask: self.cgImage!)
    tintColor.setFill()
    context.fill(rect)
    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() as! UIImage
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return newImage
}
```

Usage:

```
image.imageWithColor("#1A6BAE".UIColor)
```